# Get the Object Id

Tags: apex, salesforce-id

When I have to use an Id which is the best way to put it in a variable?

okkay hard coding an ID is bad.

Actually i'm doing:

```
 user u=[Select id,name from user where name=.. limit 1 ];     
 post.CreatedById=u.id;
```

But make this query for me is also a bad solution.

If you after change the name of the user(the same for other resources or objects) , 
get id won't work again.
This is a problem for me ever, i have this doubt everytime i'm getting an id from an object,resource..

the best solution is use custom setting?

Thanks to all for the reply.

you are very kind!

Comment: Hard-coding magic values is almost always a Bad Idea. What's your goal? CreatedById is an audit field and generally not available to be set.

Comment: i agree hard coding is bad.I've updated my question.just take a look.I haven't a goal now, but i want understand.Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If **you specifically know which user to associate** and using a query to retrieve the user Id then there are multiple places like custom labels/ custom settings where you can save the Id's and use a map/ string  and pull the ID value

say for eg. When you have to assign a region to a particular salesrep and the rep is not constant,all you do is:

Create a custom setting ( my choice) and save North america and put the user id as the Salesforce user id of the rep.

Lookup on how to create a custom setting and manage data.

If at all you feel custom settings are hard to get at the first go try custom labels. This is one way you can minimize hard coding.

[image]

In your apex class you can do :

String user_Id = Label.North_america_Rep_ID;
post.some_user_Id__c =u.id;

In the VF page you can do the same as

**UPDATE:**
This is how you make use of custom settings

```
step 1: Go to Setup--> Develope --> custom setting --> New
```

Once you hit new this is similar to creating  a new custom  object in salesforce.

```
step2: Name the custom setting and set
```

Settting Type : List
Visibility    : Public 
save the new custom setting

```
Step3: create a new custom field and choose "text" and hit next and save.

Step4: Once save is compelete go back to the custom setting and then click on manage.
Step5: You should be able to see 2 fields 1) Name 2) custom field you created
```

Think of this as a dictionary

```
Name     My custom Field
user1    005user1id
user2    005user2id
user3    005user3id
```

Once you have set up your custom setting you can use the custom setting in your apex as below

```
map<string,string> Custom_setting_map = new map<string,string>();
```

//Get all the values from the custom setting.
    for(customsetting custom: customsettingname.getall().values()){
    Custom_setting_map.put(custom.name,custom.my_custom_field__c);
    }

and then for the user1 you can do

```
    string user_id = '';
//get current user's username and check if the custom setting has the username in the key.
     if(custom_setting_map.containsKey(userinfo.getusername()){
     user_id = custom_setting_map.get(u.name));
     }
```

Comment: Thank you veru much! are custom settings the best solution?I've updated my question.Please take a look.

Comment: you can use custom settings/custom labels both are good but i would stick to custom settings due to the ease of having one custom setting and managing multiple user records

Answer (score 1):

I agree with @Mike, Hard coding values in SalesForce is always a bad idea. Here is a simple short explanation that may help.
http://pawanns-salesforce.blogspot.com/2012/12/avoiding-hardcode-recordtype-ids.html

And another with a deeper explanation and walkthrough:

http://threeheadsonapike.wordpress.com/2013/02/11/salesforce-url-hacking-prepopulating-fields/

Comment: Thanks now i'm thinking that the custom settings are the best solutions for that.Do you agree?