# How to find the EntityID for my custom object

Tags: custom-object, custom-field

I created my custom object and tried to access but there I have to provide entity ID but I dont know from where I should get the entity id for my custom object.

Comment: Try to check this questions: [How to get the ID of Custom Object](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12401/how-to-get-the-id-of-custom-object) or
[How to get Id of a object](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/5814/how-to-get-id-of-a-object) or
[Get the Object Id](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/12591/get-the-object-id)

Answer (score -2):

Use this query

select Id, ParentId, SubscriberId from EntitySubscription where ParentId =:parentObjId